# Consulta sql por varias columnas MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Quiero consultar por varias columnas con un valor concatenado, coloco el siguiente ejemplo para hacerme entender

```
-- Como se llamaría => CALL sp_getSuperConsulta("%val1% %val2% %val3%");
DROP PROCEDURE 
IF EXISTS sp_getSuperConsulta;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getSuperConsulta(IN valorConcat VARCHAR(10000))
    BEGIN
        SELECT
             *
        FROM
             tabla
        WHERE
            LOWER(CONCAT_WS(
                   ' '
                 , col1
                 , col2
                 , col3
                 , col4
            )) LIKE LOWER(valorConcat);
    END
//
```

Sería un consulta de varias columnas con varios parámetros

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema? ¿Sale algún error usando este código?

Comment: Es código de ejemplo, estuve investigando y una solución es utilizar MATCH AGAINST. Solo quiero poder realizar una consulta con palabras clave por decir: "libro, 32, roberto"

Comment: La pregunta es muy amplia y no encaja en el formato de preguntas de este sitio. Si incluyes la información de las tablas a usar y datos de ejemplo, será más fácil responder.